# Downloading Sharepoint File using Microsoft Graph API not showing content attribute

Tags: sharepoint, postman, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to download a file from SharePoint online using Microsoft Graph API.
Graph API is not allowing me to use /Content.

This is the endpoint I'm using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<host.sharepoint.com>/lists/<ListID>/items/<ItemID>
```

This is what get (Values Removed):

```
{
"@odata.context","@odata.etag","createdDateTime","eTag","id","lastModifiedDateTime","webUrl","createdBy"{"user": {"email","id","displayName"}},   "lastModifiedBy": {"user": {"email","id","displayName"}},
"parentReference": {"id"},
"contentType": {"id"},
"fields@odata.context",
"fields": {"@odata.etag","FileLeafRef","id","ContentType","Created",    "AuthorLookupId","Modified","EditorLookupId","_CheckinComment",      "LinkFilenameNoMenu","LinkFilename","DocIcon","FileSizeDisplay",       "ItemChildCount","FolderChildCount","_ComplianceFlags","_ComplianceTag",        "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime","_ComplianceTagUserId","_CommentCount",        "_LikeCount","Edit","_UIVersionString","ParentVersionStringLookupId",       "ParentLeafNameLookupId"
}
```

}

When i try to add /content  i get:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'content'.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "<ReqID>",
        "date": "<date>"
    }
}
```

}

How do i download this file using the API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}` returns [`ListItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) but `Content` is a property of [`DriveItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) which

> Represents an item within a drive, like a document, photo, video, or
>   folder resource

that's the reason this error occurs.

Given the provided endpoint it could be modified to

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem/content
```

to [download a content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0)