# Can i get the contents of historized sharepoint file with the logic app connector Get file Content (Sharepoint)?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, getfiles

I open succesfully files and grab the content of released sharepoint files.

Then i try to get an historized file and it fail.

this worked:
Siteaddress: https://domain.sharepoint.com/teams/Foldername
FilePath: /Freigegebene Dokumente/General/Filename

and this not:
Siteaddress: https://domain.sharepoint.com/teams/Foldername
FilePath: /_vti_history/1024/Freigegebene Dokumente/General/Filename

Is this possible or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you select the "Site Address" and "File Path" in the "Get file content using path" action and it can't get what you want, it seems the action can't implement this requirement.

As a workaround, maybe you can try with microsoft graph api to download the file in your `_vti_history`. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the graph api. You can add a "[HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action)" action in your logic app to call the graph api and download the file.

Comment: Thank, it sounds good. I will check it next days. I found this link here to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769894/downloading-sharepoint-file-using-microsoft-graph-api-not-showing-content-attrib