# Reading/Downloadind an excel file from my organization sharepoint with Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to read/download an excel file from a shared folder in my organization's sharepoint. At the moment, I have an Azure AD Application that I am trying to use to authenticate the access. I am using a code that I found here to test the connection and I am still getting the following error message:

```
None
{'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 3599, 'ext_expires_in': 3599, 'access_token': 'retrieved_token'}
Read file failed. Status code: 400
```

My app has the following accesses:
[image: app API permissions]

I also requested the office admin to approve the permssion from this link: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_ID_HERE}/adminconsent?client_id={CLIENT](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_ID_HERE%7D/adminconsent?client_id=%7BCLIENT) ID HERE} which I saw in another post that helped the OP, and he has approved.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import msal
import io
import pandas as pd

# Azure App Parameters
client_id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'mysecrethere'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id'

# SharePoint Parameters
sharepoint_site_url = 'https://myorganization.sharepoint.com'
excel_file_path = '/teams/group/Shared Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/myexcelfile.xlsx'

# Create a ConfidentialClientApplication instance for credentials
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# Acquire an access token using client credentials
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'], account=None)
print(result)
if not result:
    # If the token is not found in the cache, acquire a new one
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])

# Print the result to inspect its content
print(result)

if 'access_token' in result:
    # Successful
    access_token = result['access_token']
    
    # Call Microsoft Graph to read the Excel file
    graph_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/https://myorganization.sharepoint.com:/r/teams/group/Shared Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/myexcelfile.xlsx:/content'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Successful
        excel_data = io.BytesIO(response.content)
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_data)
        print(df.head())
    else:
        print(f"Read file failed. Status code: {response.status_code}")
else:
    print("Failed to get access token.")
```

Comment: The code you are using retrieves a list of users from the Microsoft Graph API and prints the display name and email address of each user. It doesn't download the file

Comment: @Rukmini Sorry, it seems I copied the wrong code. Let me edit the post.

Comment: @Rukmini Apologies again. I have edited the post.

Comment: Can you grant Sites.Read.All Microsoft Graph API permission instead of Sharepoint API permission and check

Comment: @Rukmini Sure, I need someone from IT to approve so it may take a bit, I'll let you know when I can test. Thanks.

Comment: And I can see that the URL you are passing is not valid.It must be `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem/content?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`

Comment: Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/PxI4t2f.png), I am able to read the file passing valid URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded a file in **SharePoint Site** same as you like below:

[image]

The error ***"Read file failed. Status code: 400"*** usually occurs if you are passing the invalid Graph URL/query to perform the action.

The URL must be the format **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/lists/listID/items/ItemID/driveItem/content`**

Get the list ID:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/lists
```

[image]

**List items and note the ID:**

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/lists/ListID/items
```

[image]

Modify the code by passing the correct **Microsoft Graph query** like below:

```py
import requests
import msal
import io
import pandas as pd

# Azure App Parameters
client_id = 'a6ade814-fdba-4432-b71a-5af5ea***'
client_secret = '1di8Q~2Mltdd1l8****"'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId'

# SharePoint Parameters
sharepoint_site_url = 'https://****.sharepoint.com'
#excel_file_path = 'https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk/folder1/Book.xlsx'
# Create a ConfidentialClientApplication instance for credentials
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# Acquire an access token using client credentials
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'], account=None)
print(result)
if not result:
    # If the token is not found in the cache, acquire a new one
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])

# Print the result to inspect its content
print(result)

if 'access_token' in result:
    # Successful
    access_token = result['access_token']
    
    # Call Microsoft Graph to read the Excel file
    graph_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/lists/listid/items/10/driveItem/content'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Successful
        excel_data = io.BytesIO(response.content)
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_data)
        print(df.head())
    else:
        print(f"Read file failed. Status code: {response.status_code}")
else:
    print("Failed to get access token.")
```

[image]

You will get a **`@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`**, when you click the URL, the file will get downloaded.

Make sure to grant Admin consent to **Sites.Read.All Microsoft Graph API** permission:

[image]

**Reference:**

[postman - Downloading Sharepoint File using Microsoft Graph API not showing content attribute - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769894/downloading-sharepoint-file-using-microsoft-graph-api-not-showing-content-attrib) by Vadim Gremyachev

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rukmini! Still pending they approve the new Sites.Read.All permission, but I will test as soon as I can. T

Comment: Hi again @Rukmini. Finally I have the needed app permissions. 
I am getting the ids to access the file but I am not getting the same result as you... I have my site and list ids, I can correctly identify the item id (the folder where the xlsx is) but that's it. When I run the /items get in graph I do not see any files but the folders containing them.
So now if I run the script I get a 404 error. In graph I get the same running this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/lists/listid/items/901/driveItem/content

Comment: But i am able to see the item-id inside the folder too. Did you check the complete output?

Comment: What do you mean by complete output? 
Here's the screenshot below, as you see this is a folder result. I've searched for the file name and extension, there are no csv or excel files in the result, just all the folders.
[screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/4pU4HRE)
If I navigate to the url in the graph result, is the correct folder and contains the file.

Comment: Is your file name myexcelfile.xlsx? Can you search with the file name in the output section?

Comment: I searched for it in the output and it's not there. Not the excel I need or any other file (xlsx, csx, doc, etc). I searched for different extensions and nothing. The output is just showing the 'final' folder at best.

Comment: Is your file uploaded something same like I did?

Comment: My file is in the shared documents of a teams group sharepoint, but I obtained the site id so I don't think the teams is related?
My url via web is: https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/teams/xxxxxx/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Could this be the issue?
Aside from that it's in Documents/subfolder1/subfodler2/subfolder3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256047/discussion-between-rukmini-and-tamara-dominguez-poncelas).

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Rukmini, this was the solution. My issue with graph was that we have too many items and the result was getting trimmed. This fixed it and returned everything: /items?$top=100000000